# css overclassing in nested css definitions

Tags: css, nested

In a project, I use a complex css file in which css elements are described in such a manner :

```
.content > .pages .page-content .widgets > h2{
    some attributes...
}

.content > .pages .page-content .widgets > h2 > p{
    some other attributes...
}
```

The DOM structure is as follows :

```
<div class = "page-content">
     <div class = "widgets">
         etc...
```

Many elements are described this way which are nested one in another.

Today, I need to rearrange this CSS in order to add a new div element between page-content and widgets so the structure becomes :

```
<div class = "page-content">
     <div class = "a new class or no class definition at all">
         <div class = "widgets">
             etc...
```

Is there a simple way of doing this without having to modify each CSS definition, because there are so many nested elements that finding them all would be hard and time consuming...

And again, thanks for your wise advice !

Comment: Do you even need to change? `.page-content .widgets` is a descendant selector and so it doesn't matter if there is an extra level in between.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to make a change.

You don't have a direct descendant defined between `.page-content` and `.widgets`.

Therefore it doesn't matter if you have 1 or 100 elements in between `.page-content` and `.widgets`. As long as `.widgets` is a child of `.page-content` at some stage, this selector will still apply.

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge you need not to change in the css. coz still **.widgets** will be a child of **.page-content**  so this selector will still work for you.

you could check out more information about this here

[Refer for more details](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html)